Use of the subjunctive
Long story short
I need a source which explains the "subjunctive" grammer, in details and thoroughly.
I mean every exception, every verb that can be used before or after etc.
Currently reading "The Ultimate Spanish Review and Practice", it's great, but not in subjunctive and conditional section.
Thanks in advance 

if I were you, I would begin by learning the subjunctive in English.  Kindly notice that, in the indicative, the phrase would be "I was" and not "I were".  The subjunctive has almost disappeared from English, but it is still there, behind the scenes.

@WalterMitty English does not have subjunctive and its remants do not work at all like Romance langugage subjunctives.

Your question is not accurately posed. You have to learn when the subjunctive is used. Only in some cases do verbs have to take the subjunctive. And you have to learn subjunctive conjugations of at least the most used verbs. So, your question in any case is much too broad.

I'm no expert but Wikipedia says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

@WalterMitty Yes, for purposes here, I am. In English, the "subjunctive" is basically just a few remnants: Let there be light! Let the festivities begin! May your journey be safe. (old fashioned)  I wish I were rich. were there. and a few others. WHEREAS in Spanish, the subjunctive tenses are conjugated. You have to learn the conjugations AND the uses of it. And the relationship between them does not help with the Spanish really.

I thought you might not come. Not subjunctive. An English modal verb. Translated with a subjunctive in Spanish as: Pensé que talvez no vinieras.

No, eso simplemente no existe. El conocimiento es algo que siempre está abierto a nuevos descubrimientos por lo que sería imposible plasmar en un libro todos las situaciones posibles y todas las excepciones que puedan darse, ni en el español ni en ninguna disciplina.
Lo más cercano que hay es un libro que se llama El buen uso del español, cuyo autor es quien tanto desprecio (al fin algo bueno hiciste!). Cubre bastantes situaciones, y en mi opinión está bien como material de consulta (no es para aprender). Y, de nuevo, no esperes que no queden casos que no hayan sido considerados. Y dudo que cualquiera sea capaz de escribir una lista con todos los casos en los que debería usarse el subjuntivo, ni hablar de todas las zonas grises que se dan entre el indicativo y el subjuntivo, que tan pobremente está tratado en la mayoría de los libros.
